# Server automatically shuts down at night for no apparent reason

Tags: shutdown, windows-server-2008-r2, diagnostic, event-viewer

Since a couple of weeks, I find my Windows 2008 R2 Server down every morning. I have checked the battery and it is not the problem.

I turn ON the machine and it works normally, until it shuts down on its own.

I have heard about Event Viewer,but I don't know how to use the information it provides to diagnose the issue.

How can I proceed ahead for a correct diagnostic?

Comment: Try event Viewer >system log and you can look for I belive 6006 is shut down codes but look through there and gather info to see what is happening

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a valid license?
To find out, **right click "Computer" > Properties**. At the bottom of the System window see windows activation section.
The Windows servers are automatically shutting down when unlicensed.
You can try to rearm the license (get another period of time before activation).
In startmenu search for **cmd**. Right click command prompt > run as administrator. Than type in:

> **slmgr -rearm**

reboot

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was in other duties. But i have to say that its not the case. My server has license.